# Cannot find camel routes in an external custom module

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, keycloak

I have a problem with using an external module developed by my peers.
I have an SPI keycloak module responsible for capturing user events and sending them to the module in question.
I used Camel
The problem is that camel can't find a consumer at my project level.

Here is my code

```java
from("direct://user-logged")
                .routeId("user-event-tracker")
        
                .tracing()
                .log(String.valueOf(PAYLOAD))
                .process(new TriggerUserActionProcessor())
                
                .process(new AuditUserAction(USER_ACTION, PAYLOAD))
                .to("direct://event-persist")  //i am getting her no consumer avalaible for event-persist
                .end();


    }
```

And my pom.xml

```xml
<!-- external camel library  / .jar is already present on .m2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>sm.arcao.erki</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-event-persist</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now i am getting this error message when i try to call this route from producerTemplate
`No consumers available on endpoint: direct://event-persist`

[image]

Can you help me please

Comment: Maybe the component name is different for the `user-event-persist`. Direct component is a camel provided component and since you don't have any route defined in your context for it, hence the error. Check with your peers for the component name and then replace the direct with `<peer-developed-component>://event-persist`

Comment: Hello @AshutoshVaish 
I tried that but without success

Comment: what is your tech stack camel + quarkus ?

Comment: @ErayErdem Camel + Spring

Answer (score 0):

if routebuilder not annotated with @Component you must add this in user-event-persist and spring boot scans base package and below u must configure @ComponentsScan of spring boot or forgot this and basic way create a new bean

```
@Configuration
public Class Config{

    @Bean
    public sm.arcao.erki.SomeClass(){
    return new sm.arcao.erki.SomeClass();
    }

}
```